# Bootstrap 3 Navigation Toggle not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I copied over the navbar example from the docs and it worked fine.  I made several edits and now the toggle button is not working.  I've looked at several threads in StackOverflow and haven't found anything that's helping me.  Here is my code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#addressToolBar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary navbar-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="address-selected">4203 Afton Ln</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a>4203 Afton Ln, 78744</a></li>
                    <li><a>4511 Elwood Rd, 78722</a></li>
                    <li><a>8518 FM 1826, 78736</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  add new</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a><i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i>  import</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="addressToolBar">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left address-search" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>                                                                
                </div>                                                            
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Other <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a><i class="fa fa-mail-reply"></i> export</a></li>
                        <li><a><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> get all invoices</a></li>
                        <li><a><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> billing options</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a></li>
                <li><a><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a (non-working) fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cleverKeith/upn7qtvd/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your toggle button has a lower z-index than other elements, hence you can select it. Just add this line to your CSS and problem solved :

```
.navbar-toggle {
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

[See Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ahq3PcVhnA) for reference

Answer (score 0):

Your nav toggle is working fine. The issue is being caused by this bit of code

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-primary navbar-btn" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="address-selected">4203 Afton Ln</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a>4203 Afton Ln, 78744</a></li>
        <li><a>4511 Elwood Rd, 78722</a></li>
        <li><a>8518 FM 1826, 78736</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  add new</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a><i class="fa fa-mail-forward"></i>  import</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With position relative it is covering the entire width of the nav and so the toggle button is behind it and cant be pressed.

You could look at changing the position or at adding a z-index:xxxx; to the toggle button to keep it on the top layer.